# Skype ALSA audio distorted

Tags: skype, snap

I've downloaded skype for linux both as a deb and a snap, but get this result: The audio cuts in and out really fast. It sounds distorted, sometimes better than others. Is it correct that it's using ALSA, and how can I fix this issue? Here's a video of the problem: http://www.fa2k.net/misc/VID_20180524_192918127.mp4

Edit: This seems to have been fixed when upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04. I will post that as an answer when I've confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to version 18.04, it works somewhat better. Still having a problem at times, but I recommend to try the upgrade to anyone facing this issue. (I'm not marking my own answer as a solution, since it could be better solved)